# How do I use a snort instance to protect a web server

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, subnet, snort, intrusion-detection

This is an interesting networking one!  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I suspect I am not close to resolving the issue.

I have a snort IDS instance on AWS with an IP something like 10.10.10.10, and I have a website with an IP address, something like 8.50.200.40.

I currently have this snort rule:
alert icmp any any -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"ICMP test"; sid:10000001; rev:001;)

My $HOME_NET is defined as: ipvar HOME_NET 8.50.200.40/0.

On the web server I temporarily allowed ICMP in AWS security groups.

However I cannot get the snort rule to fire, I fear that the snort box cannot see the network traffic to the web server, because it is not in the same subnet?

Is there something I can change with my AWS config?  Or have I missed a step?

Many thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is blocked unless you allow it so you need to add a rule to the EC2 instance to allow ping.  Ok you did that

Next thing to try, enable the flow log to see if the ping is getting to the VPC
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/flow-logs.html

Comment: I did...
On the web server I temporarily allowed ICMP in AWS security groups.